# Figure out which neutral to use

Tags: neutral, smart-switch

I have these two switches in the same box, that I want to replace with smart switches. That sit on two different breakers, so I assume, I cannot use the same neutral for both. However, right now, both neutrals seem to be joined together (I assume, it's ok?). Thus my question: how do I tell which one to use for which switch? Or does it not matter as long as they are different?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @RibaldEddie no, there is no dimmer. As for tools ... well, I have a voltage tester, a multimeter, a screwdriver ... :) What do you have in mind?

Comment: well the first thing to do is to look at the cables coming into the switch box. The black wires will each be paired with a corresponding white neutral in the same cable. That’s how you know which is which. Just hook the switches up so that they use the black and white wire from the same cable that delivers constant power to the switch (the line). Post a pic and we will see what you’ve got to work with.

Comment: So, that's the weird thing: looks like there are three cables: one has one of the live wires and the neutral - fair enough. The other one has the other live and two travelers. And the third one has the switched line for the first switch and the other neutral. Do I just connect first neutral to first switch, and the other one to 3-way?

Comment: it was legal in the past. Sorry I can’t see well enough from the picture what you’re describing in words. I only see two /2 cables and one /3. I have to assume one of the /2 is the line for one light and the other /2 is the load. Adding the smart switch to this light is simple. You only have the /3 left and that’s just a three-way switch. No neutral is available here so you cannot add the smart switch.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by no neutral is available. The two white wires with the yellow cap are neutrals aren't they?

Comment: are you sure the three-way switch is on the same breaker as the other light? You seemed to indicate in your questions that they are not.

Comment: @RibaldEddie no, they are on _differeny breakers_! That's actually the whole point of my question

Comment: Yeah, I know that. The two newtrals are on the right, with yellow cap on them

Comment: @Dima but one is going to the light and the other is coming from the line. Can you also post a pic of the back of the new smart switches or send us a link to the online details?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the other switch location for the 3-way switch circuit?

Answer (score 2):

OK. You've got a black hot and white neutral coming into either the bottom of the box or the top right of the box. That hot connects to the single pole rocker switch. The black hot's neutral is wire nutted to the load neutral and it's switched hot is connected to the other terminal on the single pole rocker switch. You can replace this rocker switch with a smart switch because you have a neutral. The three-way black wire is either a switched hot or an always hot but it doesn't have a neutral so you can't use a smart switch there unless you have one that doesn't require a neutral.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sounds like you are right, about the wires. I ended up wiring both switches to that one neutral, and everything seems to work though ... What am I risking here with this setup?

Comment: @Dima You risk getting a  shock. The smart switches  need a small current flow to operate the electronics in the switches. If you open the breaker for the single pole smart, normally there would be no current flowing in the neutral but since you tapped into that neutral from the other smart switch there will be a current flow in it and if you break the neutral to change an outlet or fixture and touch it and ground, zap. Likewise if you turn off the other breaker and leave the single switch on.  Only safe way is to turn off both breakers but it is still a code violation.

Comment: it's a good explanation, thanks. But isn't neutral supposed to be connected to ground anyway?

Comment: @Dima   It is, at the main panel but if you break that connection before the main panel, it's just a live wire.

Comment: @JACK nothing will keep that shock survivable. Also it will energize the neutral of a circuit totally unrelated, so when the person turns off that breaker to work on that circuit, it'll still be live.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine  Not sure how it would energize the neutral of an unrelated circuit.  The "energized" neutral would go to ground in the main panel before up streaming to a unrelated circuit neutral.

Answer (score 1):

### That's a 3-way switch.

The first thing I see is a /3 cable (black, white, red) where all 3 wires go to the same switch.  This is easy to recognize.  This is a 3-way switch, and it is a "spur end" of a 3-way switch system.  **It is totally separate from all other wires in the box**. (except safety ground).

### The rest is pretty easy

Once we remove the /3 cable from the picture, this is super easy - it's just a standard/common "power to the switch" arrangement.

It would have made more sense visually if the installer had brought the /3 cable into the far right and the other cables into the left side, and then installed a divider in the box. (but the safety ground wires do need to tie together).

### What does this tell us?

The plain switch will be an easy job - ignore the 3-way cable and switch, and it will wire up exactly like the UL-approved instructions say.

As for the 3-way, Houston, this is about the worst outcome possible for putting a smart switch *here*.   There are at least 5 different ways for a 3-way circuit to be wired. How it's wired *dictates to you* where a smart switch must be located and which types are possible to use.  Most will not work here.  There is not neutral available here, and you can't poach neutral from the other circuit. (NEC 300.3).

So the rest of the 3-way circuit will need to be mapped, and then we can figure out which smart switches are compatible with that wiring topology, and where the smart switch master must be located (probably not here), and if a smart-switch "remote" is available which will provide the functionality you want in this location.

Comment: Hm ... So, I ended up just wiring both switches to the same neutral ... Everything works, but I am sure I have violated some taboo, that will come back to hunter me :/. So the next question is how big of a deal this is, and what am I risking here?

Comment: @Dima you say "taboo" as if it's some BS requirement that doesn't matter. It's the **electrical code** and it's there for safety.  A lot of things could go wrong, including injuring someone trying to service either circuit (due to unexpected voltage on neutral *on a circuit they turned off*), a fire if "the next guy" extends your circuit further, and you also will not be able to put GFCI or AFCI protection on either circuit, as they won't tolerate stolen neutrals.

Comment: Exactly. You're putting voltage on the neutral wire from two different hot lines. Not only is it a violation of code, you're also making it so that any future person going to work on the circuits has to turn off two different and unrelated breakers to completely de-energize the neutral. This will be very unexpected and is dangerous.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine what I meant by "taboo" is that if you said something like "it is possible to do, but you should not because if neutral gets disconnected from the ground for some reason, and you shut off one of the breakers and not the other, and fail to check the voltage on the neutral, you might get slight electric shock", that would be a perfectly reasonable grounded explanation. But just just "it is _impossible_ because code" ... is just a different way to say "taboo". Thanks for the explanation though, it helps!

Comment: @Dima Let me put it this way, it can kill you, or kill someone else working on the circuits in your home.  If someone later put a receptacle off that stolen neutral it could start a fire.  But I gather you will not be swayed, because "works for me now" > "some guy on the internet says".  Can you at least, on the 3-way, tie the neutral to ground instead of the other circuit's neutral? At least that will improve safety for those working on the other circuit,and make it obvious to maintainers that it is incorrect.